# Make sure only one videoview is playing in list of videos

Tags: java, android, video

I'm using an adapter to add all videos into a list. How can I make sure that once you start another video view, all other video views stop.

I'm using a flipboard-board like animation on the video view, so only one video in the list is visible at any given time.

Is there a touch listener associated with media player that I can override? Or should I try adding all instances of the created videoview references to a static list? (Although, I read that this can cause memory issues)

Specifically, I'm using exomedia, but I figure they would have something similar to this method in Media Player.

I've tried to create some sort of touch listener, but it has awkward behavior since it is checking for any touch, when in reality it should only stop the playback on the user dragging the screen AND completely switching to the next video. (I considered using a drag listener, but I figured it would still have awkward behavior because it isn't really solving the problem).

I've also tried using VISIBILITY.VISIBLE, but that didn't seem to work (at least how I coded it.)

This is from the adapter (videoList is a List):

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View flipView = convertView;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        flipView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
    }

    final EMVideoView emVideoView = (EMVideoView) flipView.findViewById(R.id.video_view);
    emVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoURL[position]));
    emVideoView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(emVideoView.isPlaying()){
                numOfVidsPlaying++;
            }
            if(!emVideoView.isPlaying()){
                numOfVidsPlaying--;
            }
            if(numOfVidsPlaying>1){
                emVideoView.stopPlayback();
                numOfVidsPlaying--;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    return flipView;
}
```

Here is the layout:

```
<com.devbrackets.android.exomedia.ui.widget.EMVideoView
    android:id="@+id/video_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    EMVideoView:useDefaultControls="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the main "acitivity" (fragment):

```
public VideoViewFragment() {
    super();
}

private FlipViewController flipView;
private String[] videoURL;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    int videoCount = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getInt("videoCount");
    videoURL = new String[videoCount + 1];
    videoURL[0] = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("videoURL");  //TODO Make a not found exception error
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < videoCount; ++i) {
        videoURL[i + 1] = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString(("otherURL" + i));
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < videoURL.length; ++k) {
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    flipView = new FlipViewController(inflater.getContext(), FlipViewController.VERTICAL);
    flipView.setAdapter(new VideoViewAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.exo_video_view, videoURL));

    return flipView;

}
```

Comment: so the problem is that when you touch the screen videos don't stop playing?
Can you tell me exactly your problem, and what you want your programm to do?

Comment: What I'm most concerned about is more than one video playing at one time. The current behavior is that you can start one video, use the flipboard-like animation to switch to another (the former video no longer visible), start a new video  and both will be playing. Checking for touch event is just what I've tried to do.

Comment: Preferably, I need to figure out some way in which to detect that "onFlip" a video should stop playing, or "onNewVideoBeingPlayed" that the older one(s) stop.

Comment: I'm currently testing using ExoMedia's onPlayPausedListener

Comment: does  emVideoView.stopPlayback(); works? does it make current video stop playing?

Comment: Currently, the counter doesn't seem to work properly. I think that each video view contains its own instance of the numOfVidsPlaying variable and then simply causes itself to be unplayable? I don't think the TouchListener is going to work. My next idea is to pass a VideoView[] list into the constructor of the adapter and have it index each new emVideoView and track the amount playing and then pause any when there is greater than one.